# When not given the direction of motion of a body and how to consider conventions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> A particle start moving along a straight line path with a velocity 10m/s. After 5 s, the distance of the particle from the starting point is 50 m.

> Q1 So, Did the body go behind 50m or forward 50m. How to identify?

In Q2, I sometimes get confused in how to use the equations of motion.

> Q2 Let us say if I take it going behind , then s = -50 . So u will be equal to -10 also because we are considering backward direction as negative and forward as positive. So will the acceleration be negative too?

Just confused with how to take those direction values in Q2(Conventions ).

-50=-10(5)+(-a)$(t^2)$ for backward
Forward 50 = +10(5)+(a))$t^2$
They both give same answer 2/25 and -2/25.

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering backward direction as negative and forward as positive, a velocity of $+10\ \mathrm{m}.\mathrm{s}^{-1}$ during $+5\ \mathrm{s}$ gives a displacement of $+50\ \mathrm{m}$, that is in the forward direction. If the body is going backwards, its velocity is negative, so if you wait for a positive amount of time (to see what happens in the future), you get a negative displacement. All this is encapsulated in formula $v=d/t$, where quantities have a sign.

Concerning acceleration, I don't understand why you mention this, but it is somewhat different. The acceleration is the variation of speed with respects to time. So if you know only the speed and position of your system at a single instant, and if you don't know what force is driving it, you cannot deduce its acceleration

Comment: please check my edit.Your answer is really helpful.

Comment: When putting the values and sign in the formula , do we take a as + or - in both cases.

Comment: pls check my edit.@Emmy

Comment: If I understand correctly (but it is not very clear), in your edit you are considering a uniformly accelerated motion with acceleration $a$, for a body which was initially placed at the origin. So the distance it travels after time $t$ (either positive or negative), is given by $d = vt+at^2/2$ (the $/2$ is here to cancel the $2$ which appears when differentiating the square). In this equation again, the distance, velocity and acceleration can have a sign depending on the direction you consider. If you want to know the sign of the acceleration for instance, you have to isolate and compute it

Answer (score 0):

You choose a coordinate system. Then the sign of any physical quantity depends on how it acts in that system.  (Note that in 2 or 3 dimensions, a vector cannot be negative. Only a component of a vector can be negative.)